# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out while connecting through a proxy

Tags: java, url, proxy, download, urlconnection

I am trying to download a zip file from a URL and store it in the local system using java code. I am also using system proxy for the same. Its unable to connect to the url. Any idea?

```
public static void main()
{
   try
   {
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      System.out.println("Connecting to the url...\n");
      System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", " http://abc.com");
      System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","1111");

      URL url = new URL("http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.20/7z920.exe/download?use_mirror=nchc");
      url.openConnection();
      InputStream reader = url.openStream();
      FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("/home/user/result/apps.zip);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];
      int totalBytesRead = 0;
      int bytesRead = 0;

      System.out.println("Reading ZIP file 150KB blocks at a time.\n");

      while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
      {  
         writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         buffer = new byte[153600];
         totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
      }

      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      System.out.println("Done downloading. " + (new Integer(totalBytesRead).toString()) + " bytes read (" + (new Long(endTime - startTime).toString()) + " millseconds).\n");
      writer.close();
      reader.close();
   }
   catch (MalformedURLException e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   unZip(INPUT_ZIP_FILE);

}
```

i get the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:977)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:925)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at test.main(test.java:33)
```

It says unknown host when i try to ping the url, but i am able to ping urls like www.google.com

Comment: if you cannot ping how can you connect to ? Does the url work from a web browser ?

Comment: I've just checked what happens when I openConnection to that URL on my machine, and I can read data just fine. This suggests your computer is somehow unable to talk to sourceforge.net. As @BigMike suggests, see if you can actually visit that URL in a browser.

Comment: @BigMike yeah, the url works from a web browser

Comment: So you can't ping the host, but you can browse to it? Is your browser set up to run through a proxy?

Comment: @Zarkonnen I suspect the very same due to the setting of http.proxyHost, btw is http://abc.com actually an http proxy ?

Comment: @Zarkonnen i am specifying the proxy settings here in my code

Comment: @BigMike no, abc.com is just an example

Comment: @user1729154 check your proxy settings then, if the browser works there's have to be something involved with that. Are you trying your code inside some dev env tool (e.g. Eclipse) ?

Comment: i am running the code from linux

Comment: @BigMike when tried from eclipse, it runs perfectly fine

Comment: You can try setting this System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true"); like explained http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html

Comment: @user1729154 Apologies for failing to read the bit about proxies.

Comment: i am able to download the file using wget but still no luck with the java code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this [page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html) on how to work with proxies - looks comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are behind some firewall because your code is running perfectly in my local machine. I have not done any changes in your code. The zip file is downloaded in my local machine. The console shows this message:

> Connecting to the url...
>
> Reading ZIP file 150KB blocks at a time.
>
> Done downloading. 1110476 bytes read (13816 millseconds).

Comment: did you run it through eclipse or some other dev env tool?

Comment: through eclipse, even i am able to run it. but the problem starts when i try it through linux